# making the background like the attached image in CSS

Tags: css

[image]

How can I make a background like the attached image in css? I have experimented with border so that I can give it a shape like the black part, but in that case I cannot write text so I guess border shapes of parallelogram will not work any other ideas?

Comment: Is using background-image for the containing div not an option?

Comment: I want to develop it using CSS without the background image

Comment: hmm... I'm no CSS expert but I am 99% sure there is no way to get the diagonal lines in CSS2. You could try CSS3 - place a div and apply a transform; I'm fairly certain you can make parallelograms that way. Wouldn't be totally cross-browser compatible, though.

Comment: do you suggest background image in that case?

Comment: You could use a CSS3 transform and provide fallback that uses a background image. I'm going to fiddle about with it and get back to you.

Comment: oh wait, there was a way to make the diagonal using the corner of a div with wide borders, wasn't there! now I understand what you meant by borders. sorry...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write like this:
**CSS**

```
.tab{
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
    background:#000;
}
.tab:after{
    content:'';
    right:-40px;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-width:20px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #000 #000;
    border-style:solid;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/696Sb/

Y0u can also use css3 transform for this. Write like this:

```
.tab:after{
    content:'';
    right:-30px;
    top:10px;
    position:absolute;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    background:#000;
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/696Sb/1/

Comment: oh wow, that looks way better than my way. I guess it's not that surprising - 17.2k probably means you know a bit more than my 113 :-D

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 tutorials to make diagonal/triangle in CSS:

- [How to Create Diagonal Lines with CSS](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-create-diagonal-lines-with-css/)
- [CSS triangle](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

Do you want to be able to write under the uppermost black horizontal line (on left, left of the diagonal)?

Answer (score 1):

Hey now you can do this use **after** and **before** properties in css as like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="shape"></div>
```

**Css**

```
    .shape{
background:#000;
    margin:40px 20px;
    height:100px;
    width:700px;
    position:relative;
}
.shape:after{
content:'';
position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
    right:0;
    height:20px;
    border-left:solid 30px #000;
    border-right:transparent 30px solid;
        border-top:transparent 20px solid;
}


.shape:before{
content:'';
position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
    left:0;
    right:60px;
    height:20px;
background:#000;
}
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/uuxd8/

**Updated**

Live demo two http://jsfiddle.net/uuxd8/1/

Comment: I only see a black background in fiddle

Comment: @DevR what you say do you mean not show Trangle in jsfiddle but check to this http://jsfiddle.net/uuxd8/1/